# Text to Speech app not working in emulator in android studio but works in android device

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, text-to-speech

Is there some settings I have to change in the android emulator?
The app runs in the android device but doesnt run in the simulator. When I press the convert button it just doesn't output any speech at all. I even checked if other apps give output through the speaker. Yes, youtube works perfectly fine.

```
package com.example.labpgm7;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Locale;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText texttospeak;
    Button speak;
    TextToSpeech t;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        texttospeak=findViewById(R.id.texttospeech);
        t=new TextToSpeech(this, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInit(int status)
            {

            }
        });
    }

    public void speak(View v)
    {
        String text=texttospeak.getText().toString();
        t.setPitch(1.0f);
        t.setSpeechRate(1.0f);
        t.speak(text,TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH,null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason why the TTS is not working on the emulator is because the `TextToSpeech` instance creation should be performed asynchronously, not in the main UI thread.

Indeed, you have to make sure that the TTS initialisation is successful by waiting on the `onInit()` callback verifying that the status is `TextToSpeech.SUCCESS`. Language should be defined as well, for instance (used AsyncTask for demonstration only):

```
private class TTSInit extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            t=new TextToSpeech(getContext(), status -> {
                if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
                    t.setLanguage(Locale.ENGLISH);
                    /* now you can invoke speak() */
                }
            });
            return null;
        }
}
```

Finally, if you're targeting Android 11, the following code should be added into the manifest:

```
<queries>
    <intent>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.TTS_SERVICE" />
    </intent>
</queries>
```

Comment: @Farman M does the answer above help in figuring out the issue?

Comment: I could not get TTS working on an emulator and it worked after adding that `action` thing. But how come the same code worked on real devices? Why don't real devices require that `action`?

Comment: In my case, I only had the `MainActivity` which implemented `TextToSpeech.OnInitListener`. It didn't work with an emulated API 30 but worked with API 24.
What fixed it for API 30 was adding the Manifest part.